# iOS Building Form with Checkboxes

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm building a form with checkboxes in my app, and of course, the XCode library doesn't actually provide checkboxes as a form option (crazy); so I've created buttons with images resembling checkboxes (checked/unchecked).

That said, my form is quite long, and requires 20+ checkboxes - and if I'm understanding correctly, each checkbox has to be "wired" individually; **e.g.** for three checkboxes on my screen, see the below code...  I can't imagine having to do ALL of this for 20 checkboxes (let alone 3!) - is there a better way to do this? Help/suggestions are greatly appreciated.

**.h**

```
@interface PetRegistrationViewController : UIViewController {

    BOOL checked1;
    BOOL checked2;
    BOOL checked3;

}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *checkboxButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *checkboxButton2;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *checkboxButton3;


- (IBAction)checkButton:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)checkButton2:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)checkButton3:(id)sender;
```

**.m**

```
@synthesize checkboxButton;
@synthesize checkboxButton2;
@synthesize checkboxButton3;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    checked1 = NO;
    checked2 = NO;
    checked3 = NO;

}

- (IBAction)checkButton:(id)sender {

    if (!checked1) {

       [checkboxButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
      checked1 = YES;


        NSLog(@"button 1");
    }

    else if (checked1) {

        [checkboxButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        checked1 = NO;

    }


}

- (IBAction)checkButton2:(id)sender {


    if (!checked2) {

        [checkboxButton2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        checked2 = YES;

        NSLog(@"button 2");
    }

    else if (checked2) {

        [checkboxButton2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        checked2 = NO;

    }

}

- (IBAction)checkButton3:(id)sender {

    if (!checked3) {

        [checkboxButton3 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        checked3 = YES;


        NSLog(@"button 3");
    }

    else if (checked3) {

        [checkboxButton3 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        checked3 = NO;

    }

}
```

Comment: i think you should use a UITableView. you can store the cells (e.g. @property NSArray<UITableViewCell*> *cells) and you don't have to dequeue them. otherwise, laying out +20 form field can be painful. you can handle button taps within cell class. i hope that may help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take 3 buttons, Take 2 images - lets say one is checked and other is unchecked.

Now go to attribute inspector in storyboard (the second option in the top right side), and find the place where it says "selected image" "deselected image", right after selecting the button (any one of them), in the storyboard.

Put the checked image as the selected image, and the unchecked as the deselected image, and put the unchecked image as the default image.

Set tag 1,2,3 for the three buttons respectively.

Now for some code.

Write a single IBAction method and connect all three button's action to that method.

```
-(IBAction)actionMethodButton:(id)sender{
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;
     [self swapImagesOfButtons:btn];
      switch(btn.tag){
          case: 1{
              //Button 1;
           }
           break;
           case : 2 {
               //Button 2;
           }
           break;
           case : 3{
                //Button 3;
           }
           break;
           default :{
           }
           break;
      }
}
```

Write another method to just swap the images ---

```
   -(void)swapImagesOfButtons:(UIButton *)btn{

        if(btn.selected ){
             [btn setSelected : NO]; // if button is selected, you are deselecting it.
         }
         else {
             [btn setSelected : YES];
         }
     }
```

Comment: Ahh good to know. That said, the purpose of checking the boxes is to eventually send the data represented by each to a database. E.g. if boxes 1 and 2 are checked of 3, I want uilabel 1 and 2 to post to my database - is this possible going this route?

Comment: editing the answer, accordingly and this method would do quite good. only if you can apply a switch case, that is why i said to set tag for each button

Comment: Have edited the answer, i guess this would suit your requirement well.

Answer (score 0):

You can have one action method for all the 20 buttons. In the storybaord, you can give tag to each button.

And you can do like:

```
-(IBAction)actionMethod:(id)sender{

       UIButton *btn=(UIButton *)sender;
      if(btn.tag==1){
           [self toggleImageForButton:btn];
            //execute button 1  other action 
          }
      if(btn.tag==2){// execute button 2 action}
       .....
      if(btn.tag==20){// execute button 20 action}
  }

-(void)toggleImageForButton:(UIButton *)btn{
if (btn.selected) {
       [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }
    else  {
        [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }
}
```

You can also use button title instead of tag to compare.

Connect all the 20 buttons to this method.

You can look into **IBOutletCollection**, for declaring all the 20 buttons as an array, and later modifying the IBOutletCollection property.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *buttons;
```

later you can access the button properties like:

```
      for (UIButton *btn in buttons) {
       //access btn properties
        }
```

Please note that the order of an outlet collection appears to be roughly the order in which their connections are established in Interface Builder.

Comment: Noted; and each button still needs its own property then yes?

Comment: look into IBOutletCollection @Brittany to have all the outlets tied together.

Answer (score 0):

=> you can use button tag along that use below code eas way to achieve checked and unchecked  like below try it:

ou shouldn't need to subclass the UIButton class. By design, Objective-C favors composition over inheritance.

UIButton is a subclass of UIControl, which has a selected property. You can use this property to toggle the on/off behaviour of a checkbox, just the same way a UISwitch does.

You can attach an action to the button's touched up inside event, and perform the toggling in there, something like this:

[myCheckBoxButton setImage:nonCheckedImage forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[myCheckBoxButton setImage:nonCheckedImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

- (void)myCheckboxToggle:(id)sender
  {
  myCheckboxButton.selected = !myCheckboxButton.selected; // toggle the selected property, just a simple BOOL
  }